# Is it OK to mention dreams and future plans for a specific company in my SOP when applying for master's degree?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I am about to apply for Master's degree at a University in US that specializes in game development. I have been playing and I am a huge fan of Blizzard games for almost 15 years and the reason I pursue a higher education is to broaden my knowledge and sharpen my skills so that I can land on my dream job.

I wanted to mention this (in a politically correct manner) because I think it shows determination. Is this a good idea or would it hurt my statement?

Comment: this comment might be late, but why do you want to be a game maker, not a professional gamer? The answer will go to your SOP.

Comment: @Ooker that is what happened and I'm just about to finish my first semester after I deliver my game engine project in 48h :)

Comment: good luck to you :). I'm always a zealot of StarCraft :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike the other existing answer, I would advise you to tread carefully.

- *Maybe* this is different for a Master's in game development, but generally speaking, "I like to play computer games" qualifies as the #1 worst reason we get to hear about why students are interested in computer science. One of the reasons why this is such a bad motivation is because it shows a certain level of misunderstanding about what computer science is, and I would argue that this is even true for a master in game development.
- Even great computer game developers are, to the best of my knowledge, not *only* interested in gaming, but also in AI, computer graphics and animation, HCI, physical simulation, distributed systems, optimization, etc. Not all of them at the same time, but being "just" interested in building cool games seems rather weak, to be honest. I think it can be pretty much implied that you are interested in games if you apply for game development. Show and discuss your interests in other related areas that sets you apart from all the other applying gamers.
- Also, having working at Blizzard as your dream job does *not* show determination. Many people have this as their dream job, and still do not follow through. Determination is doing something to make your dream a reality despite problematic circumstances, not having a dream in the first place. You should explain what you did, not what you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea. The statement of purpose should explain why you specifically should get the opportunity to do a Masters, and having a good plan for what you want to do with it is definitely a plus there.

I would however caution you that pretty much everyone who applies to such a Maters degree probably has similar plans and a similar background with a lot of playing games. Therefore, you should try to be a bit more specific than what you have here. What sets you apart from everyone else who has played a lot of games and wants to work for Blizzard?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the caution. I think I got that part covered (hopefully) by mentioning my academic studies, projects and my mentality while studying undergrad. Too bad I failed to mention that I am applying for a master's degree :) Does your argument of it being a good idea still hold?